# What is Sha'arei HaAnavah?

Tags: jewish-books, mussar-ethics, rabbeinu-yonah

Rabbeinu Yonah ([Sha'arei Teshuvah 1:24](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38229&pgnum=14)) mentions "Sha'arei HaAnavah". What is this? I have never seen a book by that name attributed to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2 possible answers.

Per [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94) a large part of this Sefer was lost. Perhaps the Sha'arei HaAnavah is part of the lost Sefer.

[Orchos Tzadikim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/orhot/shaar-2.htm) author is unknown and it has a [Sha'arei HaAnavah](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/orhot/2-2.htm). Woluld it be possible that this is written by Rabbeinu Yonah?

Comment: It's interesting that Wikipedia doesn't include Sha'arei HaAnavah as one of the lost books of Sha'arei Tzedek. (But I don't think it's plausible that Orchos Tzadikim was written by Rabbeinu Yonah: It appeared 2 centuries after Rabbeinu Yonah's death, and was published in Germany even though Rabbeinu Yonah lived in Gerona, Spain. Though it's possible that the book Sha'arei HaAnavah was available to the author of Orchos Tzadikim and he copied some material from it, just like he "plagiarized" a lot from Sha'arei Teshuvah itself in his Sha'ar HaTeshuvah.)